# Lighting in WebGL on Galaxy S3 smartphone

Tags: android, firefox, webgl, galaxy

At [glowscript.org](http://glowscript.org) are various demo programs written in JavaScript or CoffeeScript that involve little code.

For example, the one-line program `box()` creates a 3D cube that can be rotated and zoomed, thanks to many defaults (which can be overridden), including basic lighting (two distant lights and some ambient lighting).

### Problem:

These programs run fine in many browsers on Windows, Mac, and Linux, but in *Firefox on the Samsung Galaxy S3* they are very dark. The appearance indicates that ambient light works (increasing it makes the scene bright) but the distant lights don't work (no difference with them on or off). I've tried running some WebGL demos found on the web and they look fine.

**Can anyone think of where I should look for the problem? Why should the behavior be so different between desktop/laptop behavior and what happens on the Galaxy S3?**

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem on the Galaxy smartphone and added the following to the GlowScript help:

"Most tablets and smart phones do not yet support WebGL, though this is likely to change. On the Samsung Galaxy S3 smartphone, Firefox and Opera do run GlowScript programs, though animations are slow, transparency is buggy, and currently there is no way to zoom and rotate. There are reports that GlowScript also works on the Sony Experia smartphone."

The problem was that the Galaxy shader compiler does not handle for loops correctly. In the fragment shader there was a for loop over the various lights (up to 8 lights). Variables set in the for loop were often set to zero instead of to the specified value. The solution consisted of replacing the loop with a straight-line structure like this, where LP(i) and LC(i) are light positions and colors:

```
if (light_count == 0) return;
calc_color(LP(0), LC(0));
if (light_count == 1) return;
calc_color(LP(1), LC(1));
if (light_count == 2) return;
etc.
```

Yuck. Fortunately we only have to support a finite number of lights.